# Optaplanner / Drools throws exception in solverFactory.buildSolver()

Tags: java, enums, drools, optaplanner

I don't know what the cause of this is but googling it suggests something to do with enums.

I have one enum that i am using for optaplanner, but in former iterations (possibly an older version of optaplnner or drools) this wasn't an issue

Update:

i have removed the one enum that was used from the planning entity and this is still happening

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.kie.internal.builder.conf.LanguageLevelOption.useJavaAnnotations()Z
```

StackTrace:

```
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.normalizeTypeDeclarationAnnotations(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:2288)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.normalizeTypeAnnotations(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:126)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:116)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:243)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:64)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:230)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:198)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:447)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:298)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:230)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:233)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:52)
```

SolverConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
<environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>

<!-- Domain model configuration -->
<solutionClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.ActivitySolution</solutionClass>
<entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTask</entityClass>
<entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTaskResourceAllocation</entityClass>

<!-- Score configuration -->
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <scoreDrl>com/rdthree/plenty/services/activities/planner/activity-scoring.drl</scoreDrl>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
<termination>
    <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
    <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0soft</bestScoreLimit>
    <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
</termination>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="resourceAllocationSelector">
            <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTaskResourceAllocation</entityClass>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="resourceAllocationSelector" />
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>resource</variableName>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="taskSelector">
            <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTask</entityClass>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="taskSelector" />
            <filterClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.filters.TaskLengthChnageFilter</filterClass>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>interval</variableName>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>

<localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
        <moveListFactory>
            <fixedProbabilityWeight>2.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
            <moveListFactoryClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.MoveResourceAllocationMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
            <filterClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.filters.TaskLengthChnageFilter</filterClass>
            <entitySelector id="taskMoveSelector">
                <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTask</entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>interval</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>

    <acceptor>
        <valueTabuSize>7</valueTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>2000</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
</localSearch>
```

Comment: Check the versions of the kie, drools and optaplanner jars in your classpath, they should be the same. If you're using maven, do `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSuchMethodError only happens when your classpath is messed up. Looks like the `kie-internal` and the `drools-compiler` jar don't have the same version.

Comment: Thanks, i matched the version on my kie and optaplanner in maven and that solved it.